# send the POST without URLencoding the data

Tags: forms, encoding

I post a form,and the value is

```
<
```

But It last be enocded

```
%3C
```

So,how I keep `<`? or send the POST  without URLencoding the data.

Comment: How do you send the form (show your code)? Where and how is it encoded in the request (capture the request and show it)? Why do you want to send it unencoded (doesn't the server understand HTTP, or do you send the wrong encoding headers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your forms `enctype` value to `text/plain`. The only encoding done by that is to replace spaces with `+` symbols.